# Can't display validation errors with kartik-v bootstrap file input plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've opened an issue on the github plugin, but it doesn't seem to be very active, so I asked here too.

I'm sending my files through ajax but when the upload fails (as with height too small) I don't get the real error message, but I get an error from my ajax url, but this one makes no sense since nothing is sent.
I think the ajax route shouldn't be called, but anyway, I tried to play with 'fileuploaderror' and I do get the wanted errors, but I don't know how to display them. There must be a simple way in the fileuploaderror event, but I don't know it.
Can anyone help me with this one ?

[Issue link](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput/issues/810) | 
[Plugin page](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input)

Thanks

```
$("#id").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "/ajax/snippet/image/send/78", // server upload action
    deleteUrl: "/ajax/snippet/image/remove/",
    uploadAsync: false,
    showUpload: false, // hide upload button
    showRemove: false, // hide remove button
    maxFileCount: maxFile,
    browseOnZoneClick: true,
    language: "fr",
    minImageWidth: 150,
    minImageHeight: 150,
    allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp", "png"],
    multiple: true,
    maxFileSize: 5000,
    uploadExtraData: function (previewId, index) {
        return {key: index};
    },
    initialPreviewAsData: true,
    overwriteInitial: false,
    }).on("filebatchselected", function (event, files) {
        // trigger upload method immediately after files are selected
        $(this).fileinput("upload");
    }).on('fileuploaderror', function (event, data, msg) {
        var form = data.form, files = data.files, extra = data.extra,
                response = data.response, reader = data.reader;
        // get message
        alert(msg);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer, in my "filebatchselected" event, I was forcing the upload.

I need to check if I have valid files to upload first.

```
$("#id").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "/ajax/snippet/image/send/78", // server upload action
    deleteUrl: "/ajax/snippet/image/remove/",
    uploadAsync: false,
    showUpload: false, // hide upload button
    showRemove: false, // hide remove button
    maxFileCount: maxFile,
    browseOnZoneClick: true,
    language: "fr",
    minImageWidth: 150,
    minImageHeight: 150,
    allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp", "png"],
    multiple: true,
    maxFileSize: 5000,
    uploadExtraData: function (previewId, index) {
        return {key: index};
    },
    initialPreviewAsData: true,
    overwriteInitial: false,
    }).on("filebatchselected", function (event, files) {
        // trigger upload method immediately after files are selected
        var filesStack = $('#input-id').fileinput('getFileStack');
        if (filesStack.length > 0) {
            $(this).fileinput("upload");
        }
    });
}
```